# How to override a method in a custom library class

Tags: c#, oop, namespaces, overriding

I have two projects: `ClientProj` and `ServerProj`, which both share a `SharedLibrary` containing the basics of my game.

Inside this library I have the class `GameObject` which is the base class from which many other game items inherit.

Inside `GameObject` is a `SetPosition()` method.

**Here's my problem:** When I run `SetPosition()` on the client, I wish to add some additional code / override the method completely. The code I wish to add however relates to classes that are only present in the `ClientProj` namespace, which the `SharedLibrary` knows nothing about.

Is there any clean way to override or extend the library methods?

*Updated: Note that the instances of GameObject and all things that inherit it are defined, contained and handled all within the SharedLibrary namespace. For the most part the ClientProj and ServerProj only handle networking, users and input/output.*

Comment: If the definition of the overridden SetPosition method doesn't include references to the classes in your client library, I don't see what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) and have the game objects inherit from the proxy class instead of the real class:

*SharedLibrary:*

```
public class GameObject
{
    public virtual void SetPosition() { ... }
}

public class DelegatingGameObject : GameObject
{
    public GameObject Inner;
    public override void SetPosition() { Inner.SetPosition(); }
}

public class Tree : DelegatingGameObject
{
}
```

*ClientLibrary:*

```
class ClientGameObject : GameObject
{
    public override void SetPosition()
    {
        if (isMonday) base.SetPosition();
    }
}

var tree = new Tree { Inner = new ClientGameObject() };
tree.SetPosition();
```

---

*SharedLibrary:*

```
public class GameObject
{
    public virtual void SetPosition() { Console.WriteLine("GameObject.SetPosition"); }
    public static event Func<GameObject> Factory;
    internal static GameObject CreateBase() { var factory = Factory; return (factory != null) ? factory() : new GameObject(); }
}

internal class GameObjectBase : GameObject
{
    private readonly GameObject baseGameObject;
    protected GameObjectBase() { baseGameObject = GameObject.CreateBase(); }
    public override void SetPosition() { baseGameObject.SetPosition(); }
}

internal class Tree : GameObjectBase
{
    public override void SetPosition()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tree.SetPosition");
        base.SetPosition();
    }
}

public static class Game
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        new Tree().SetPosition();
    }
}
```

*ClientLibrary:*

```
internal class ClientGameObject : GameObject
{
    public override void SetPosition()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClientGameObject.SetPosition Before");
        base.SetPosition();
        Console.WriteLine("ClientGameObject.SetPosition After");
    }
}

internal static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GameObject.Factory += () => new ClientGameObject();
        Game.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you're suggesting, but my dilemma is that the instances of GameObject and all the things that inherit it are defined, contained and handled all within the SharedLibrary namespace. For the most part the ClientProj and ServerProj only handle networking, users and input/output. Therefore it's gonna be nigh impossible to pull the object definitions out and into the ClientProj so that your suggestion can be implemented.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to move the `Tree` from the SharedLibrary into the ClientProj. Do you want `Tree` to be `internal` or what's the problem?

Comment: The `Tree` object is only ever instanced from inside the `SharedLibrary` and thus the Client override is outside of its scope.

Comment: I see. But GameObject and SetPosition are public, right? Otherwise the ClientProj couldn't override it.

Comment: Aha, the updated code looks promising. So you're suggesting a static constructor of sorts which can then be modified by the client when it loads the library to instead instance the overriding code. I'll have a look into this and get back to you (tomorrow). Thanks

Comment: Right, I've managed to implement your suggestion (with some modifications). The one problem I found was that `baseGameObject` is not the same instance as `GameObjectBase` itself, so when I ran `baseGameObject.SetPosition()` it set the position of `baseGameObject` instead of the object itself. This turns out to be no problem for me however: In the override I simply called `base.SetPosition()` in addition to the `baseGameObject.SetPosition()` that contains my client override... So problem solved. Thanks dtb!

Answer (score 1):

Make SetPosition method virtual and use override keyword to override its behaviour in ClientProj.

Comment: I see what you're suggesting, but in order for the ClientProj namespace to override all original instances of GameObject requires overrides in pretty much the entire library...

E.g for: public class Asteroid : GameObject
... we add: public class ClientAsteroid : ClientGameObject

I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it `virtual` in base class, override in `derived`, and in overriden method call your methods and after `base` class method.

A *psudocode* can look like this:

```
public class GameObject 
{
    public virtual void SetPosition()
    {
       //do something here 
    }
}


public class Derived: GameObject
{
    public override void SetPosition()
    {
       // do something specific to Derived
       base.SetPosition(); // CALL BASE CLASS METHOD AFTER
    }
}
```